# Sum of radicals positivity

Tags: summation, roots, radicals, python, machine-precision

I have a sum of square roots each with a coefficient, for example like this:

```
√2 + 2√3 - 4√5 + 2√6 + ...
```

How do I know if the sum is positive or negative without calculating each square root and thus the actual sum?

Background: I am working on a data type for python which uses integers in its inner structure to store square roots. The type uses the idea, that the integers in python can be infinitely big and precise, not like the floats. This data type is very practical to calculate different things, for example the Fibonacci numbers using the golden ration `φ`. My data type is so far ready, but the only operator is missing is the comparison. Comparing sums of square roots means proving the sign of their difference.

Edit: Apparently this is a still open problem and is yet not solved: [Sum of radicals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_radicals)

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to be easy...$485\sqrt {2}-396\sqrt 3\approx 0.00146$ for example.

Comment: @lulu , I am reworking my old library and I once already solved it using the idea, that `geometrical mean < arithmetical mean < root square mean`. However I do not remember how I did this and I am not sure that my old solution was perfect

Comment: Those are inequalities involving non-negative terms...

Comment: For $2$ terms, there's probably something you can do with continued fractions (that's how I produced the example I used).  Not sure that's any easier than just approximating each term though.

Comment: already proving it is non zero seems challenging https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/